VirtualBox Ubuntu not booting after update
I'm running a 22.04 Ubuntu on a VirtualBox in Windows 11. While running updates on my other systems on Monday morning I inadvertently updated the Ubuntu to 24.04 without thinking. Now it does not boot, but displays

error: no server is specified. 
error: no suitable video mode found. 
error: symbol `grub_abort´ not found. 
error: sparse file not allowed. 
452: out of range pointer: 0x100010

I tried F12 on startup and booting it from different disk images (22.04 and 24.04) but neither work. I also used the Try Ubuntu boot option and tried running Boot-Repair, which did not work due to EFI options, which I found no advice about when dealing with a VM.
I have no snapshots of this VM to revert to (I know, a huge mistake); what are my options now?

Your GRUB bootloader is broken. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair https://superuser.com/questions/376470/how-to-reinstall-grub2-efi
